# Can't resolve 'jquery' in angular

Tags: jquery, node.js, angularjs, angular

I am having a weird issue with **jQuery** in my **Angular+TypeScript** project. I installed the following packages

```
$ npm i jquery
$ npm i @types/jquery
```

And added the script to `angular.json`

```js
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js" 
],
```

I include the package like this in `app.component.ts`

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Still, I receive this issue:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in ...
```

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

[image]

Comment: Stop using jquery this is 2020

Comment: https://therichpost.com/how-to-run-jquery-in-angular-6/

Comment: it reflects exacly my steps, it doesn't work

Comment: I suggest you to not use jquery if possible. However, your problem could be version of jquery what is angular version and jquery version in package.json ?

Comment: try deleting node_modules folder and do npm install